# How to design a full width bar with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, width

I would like to create a full width navigation bar that fits to *100%* of width of the page, like the bar of this web, the one that contains *Inicio | Actividad | Comunicaciones:

> https://community.jivesoftware.com/welcome

I would like to use only `HTML` and `CSS`. On the other hand, the bar has not to be in the top.

I would like to do something very similar to the picture, but I don't know how to achieve that

Please share a simple example! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a statement of desire not a question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your bar within a div with some id like

```
<div id="mybar">
    <!-- your HTML -->
</div>
```

On CSS, use following properties

```
#mybar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out that I did for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/x6PrR/

It shows how to do this and add another DIV to get some nice padding / spacing in there.

Good luck!

**EDIT:**

*HTML*

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav-inner">
        <p>Some navigations stuff...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- we set the first DIV to full width 100%. Because we do this, we can't add padding because that will make it larger than 100%...weird I know. A way around this is to then add another DIV inside to create the padding that has a width of AUTO. -->
```

*CSS*

```
#nav { float: left; clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #222; }
#nav-inner { float: left; clear: both; width: auto; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px; background: transparent; }
p { color: #fff; font-family: arial; font-weight: bold; }
```